# JavaScript. Как делать поиск по тегам на ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, поиск

Пытаюсь сделать на сайте поиск по тегам.
Нашел статью. Там просто пишут как делать поиск имен. Каждое имя прописана в базе данных.
Когда в поисковике набираешь имя то можно найти имя которое есть в базе данных. Думаю это похожий пример для тегов.

У меня же не получается так сделать, просто не чего не выводиться в поисковике.
[Вот сама статься](http://sozdatisite.ru/skripty/sozdanie-zhivogo-poiska-dlya-sajta-s-pomoshhyu-php-ajax-javascript)

Вот как я делаю, показываю на скриншотах:

Файл index.php:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл с подключение к базе данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл handler.php, как я понял для обработки ajax запросов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл Script где сам JS и ajax запрос.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скриншот с базой данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете мне подсказать что за ошибка? Код просто вообще не работает, не могу понять из-за чего. Сам проверял, база данных работает, на ней пароль и login верные. В чем тогда проблема? Долго уже ищу и узнаю и не могу понять почему не работает код и на поиск не выводит имена.

Делаю все ради обучение.

Comment: Приложите весь код и данные в виде текста, пожалуйста

Comment: когда что-то не работает - включаются средства вывода ошибок, а также отладка - для просмотра кода пошагово

Comment: Здравствуйте @Алексей Шиманский! Могу вам просто скинуть файл с проектом. 
И да, можете уточнить? Что такое  " отладка - для просмотра кода пошагово"? Можете мне тогда показать как ее включить?

Comment: См. Ссылки вверху. Там всё написано